# MainPage Access XAML C# wp 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, authentication

I am trying bypass the login page of an app I am playing with as I learn how to develop for windows phone. I have managed to make a working login form that authenticates with some server. however I will like to know how to Bypass the login page if the user has logged in before. like when you open the app it takes you to the content page instead of taking you to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `IsolatedStorage` and save the password (or some encrypted version of it) there.

When the user logs in, you save it there:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["PASSW"] = value;
```

When the user enters the application the next time, you check, if tehre is a value for that key there:

```
if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("PASSW"))
{
    return true //just an example
}
```

if the key exists, then just log in the user automatically. Of course this is only a trivial example, but it should illustrate the logic behind it.

Comment: I am reading about credential locker I have manage to add my password to the password vault. I am having a hard time thinking on how to log in automatically with it.

Comment: well just perform the login as you would normally, but instaed of asking the user to type in his or hers credentials, pretend that they did, any supply them from the vault.